# How does excel assign an index number to pivot tables, pivot RowFields, etc.?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, pivot-table

If I have *n* pivot tables on a worksheet (and I know their .Name property), I can run the following code to identify what Index number Excel has assigned to each pivot table:

```
Debug.Print wks.PivotTables(x).Name
```

Where *x <= n*.

When doing this I find that, if I add another pivot table, it's not always the case that the new pivot table will be PivotTable with index number *n + 1*.

Additionally, if I have a pivot table *x* with *m* RowFields in it, I can run the following code to identify what Index number Excel has assigned to each RowFields number:

```
Debug.Print wks_Pivots.PivotTables(x).RowFields(y).Name
```

Where *y <= m*.

And again I find that, if I add another RowField, it isn't necessarily the case that the new RowField will be RowField with index number *m + 1*.

So my question is, how does Excel order PivotTables and RowFields? I imagine it would apply to anything the Excel indexes.

I've tried googling the problem, and working out a pattern (it's not chronological or alphabetical) and I can't see it. Can anyone help?

Comment: For me at least, Pivottables are indexed 1,2,3,4,5 etc. by creation time, but the indexing restarts for each sheet in a workbook.

Comment: Odd. I just added another pivot table to a worksheet and it's
 wks_pivots.PivotTables(1)! Seems random to me.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F3 to see the names of your objects, it might make more sense then.